# Trying to get out of the thread in order to stop the recording in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyaudio

I am trying to build an audio recorder using python. The code is:

```
import threading
import pyaudio
import wave
class App():
    chunk = 1024 
    sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16 
    channels = 2
    fs = 44100  

    frames = []  


    def startrecording(self):
        self.p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.isrecording = True
    
        print('Recording')
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.record)
        t.start()

    def stoprecording(self):
        self.isrecording = False
        print('recording complete')
        self.filename = (r'File_path')
        self.filename = self.filename+".wav"
        wf = wave.open(self.filename, 'wb')
        wf.setnchannels(self.channels)
        wf.setsampwidth(self.p.get_sample_size(self.sample_format))
        wf.setframerate(self.fs)
        wf.writeframes(b''.join(self.frames))
        wf.close()

    def record(self):
   
        while self.isrecording:
            data = self.stream.read(self.chunk)
            self.frames.append(data)
```

The problem I am facing is when I call the startrecording function the recording starts. When I call stoprecording function the recording stops and the .wav file is saved to the defined path. But when I call the startrecording function and stoprecording function I get a .wav file which is contains recording from the previously saved file also. In short the threding is not stopped and every time I stoprecording function it gives me a file containing the recording right from the initial time I have started recording till the latest time when I have stoprecording function.

```
For ex.
File 1 =10s
File 2 =12s
But I am getting File2 = 10+12=22s
```

Answer (score 0):

The self.frames data is being initialized as an empty list, and your record function appends data to self.frames, whether it's empty or not.
If you reset self.frames to an empty list in the startrecording function, you should get the results you expect.